# Varnish only cache assets from single session

Tags: reverse-proxy, cache, varnish, magento

Currently I manage to configure varnish to cache items from 1 user, but the when the second users comes in varnish fetch another asset from Apache.

How can I cache  static assets behind magento ( css, js , image pdf etc ) accessible from multiple users ?

On vcl_recv, I've configured :

```
   if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        return (lookup);
    }
```

On vcl_fetch :

```
if (beresp.status == 200 || beresp.status == 301 || beresp.status == 404) {
if (beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/html" || beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "text/xml") 
{
    # do something
} else {
    unset beresp.http.expires;
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 300h;
}
```

I suspect this this has something to do vcl_hash that store the cache with some kind of client's fingerprint.

Is there a way to manipulate the way it hash only for certain asset types ?

EDIT 1: 
Full config : http://pastebin.com/mzSVpEqN

Comment: You're right about `vcl_hash`. Post your `vcl_hash` portion as well, or if it is ok with you, post your entire vcl file.

Comment: Full config added.

Comment: Yeah, you are hashing data per host or ip depending on your conditions, so content is cached for users whose browsing meets those conditions. Comment out the vcl_hash function as see what you get.

Comment: Also, do you need the vcl_hash function for something else?

Comment: At this point I dont need vcl_has to do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the way to solve this.

Varnish store different cached page for each specific User-Agent. I found the following technique to normalize user agent ( https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleNormalizeUserAgent )

I just put everything into 1 basket and see huge increase in the number of hits.

On vcl_recv:

```
if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
     set req.http.user-agent = "Mozilla";
     unset req.http.Https;
     unset req.http.cookie;
     return (lookup);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, comment out the `vcl_hash` function (provided you don't need it for anything else) and hopefully you should see improvements.

HTH!

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't help. Is there anyway to print out the hash value?

Comment: Start by examining what is being sent to the backend, especially cookies: `varnishtop -i TxHeader -I Cookie`

Comment: Thanks KM01 .. Your suggestion point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish will honor Vary headers from the backend. Unless the backend sends Vary: User-Agent, there's no reason to normalize the User-Agent client header.